# tax_query not working?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, tax-query

tax_query is not working, inside the eachloop I'm trying to echo `$use_case_category->slug;` and getting all the taxonomies on the screen and not the ones selected by bootstrap tabs. All the rest of the code works fine, but when it comes to filtering the posts by taxonomies by clicking on the tabs, it's not working. The code:

```
function custom_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Types',
        'singular_name' => 'Type',
        'search_items' => 'Search Types',
        'all_items' => 'All Types',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Type',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Type:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Type',
        'update_item' => 'Update Type',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Custom Type',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Type Name',
        'menu_name' => 'Type'
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'type')
    );

    register_taxonomy('type', array('use_cases'), $args);
    global $use_case_categories;
    $use_case_categories = get_terms('type');
}

    // Shortcode for Use Cases caption

    add_shortcode('Use_Case', 'use_case_shortcode_query');
    function use_case_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
        global $use_case_categories;
      extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
       'posts_per_page' => '11',
       'post_type' => 'use_cases',
            )
       , $atts));

      global $post;

      $posts = new WP_Query(array(
       'posts_per_page' => 11,
       'post_type' => 'use_cases'
            ));
        //print_r($posts);
      $output = '';

    $out = '';
    $out .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">';
    $out .= '<li class="active">';
    $out .= '<a data-toggle="tab" href="#all">All</a>';
    $out .= '</li>';
    foreach($use_case_categories as $use_case_category):
    $out .= '<li>';
      $out .= '<a href="#' . $use_case_category->slug . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $use_case_category->name . '</a>';
    $out .= '</li>';
    endforeach;
    $out .= '</ul>';
    ?>



    <?php
    $out .= '<div class="tab-pane active" id="all"';
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'use_cases',
        'posts_per_page' => 11,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $all_films = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $all_films->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $all_films->have_posts() ) : $all_films->the_post();

        $out .= '<a href='.get_post_meta($post->ID, "location", true).'><div class="vce-row vce-element--has-background vce-row--col-gap-30 use_case_finance vce-row-equal-height vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-6cc8dbe6" data-vce-do-apply="all el-6cc8dbe6"><div class="vce-content-background-container"></div><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-f4a5f49c" data-vce-do-apply="background el-f4a5f49c"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-f4a5f49c"><div class="vce-row-container"><div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-356c02e5" data-vce-do-apply="all el-356c02e5"><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-4c08b71e" data-vce-do-apply="background el-4c08b71e"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-4c08b71e"><div class="vce-row-container"><div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-86253324" data-vce-do-apply="all el-86253324"><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-a1c3851f" data-vce-do-apply="background el-a1c3851f"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-a1c3851f"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading vce-google-fonts-heading--align-center vce-google-fonts-heading--color-b-72-72-72--45--5C00FF--FF7200"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-wrapper"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading--background vce" id="el-5c7b806f" data-vce-do-apply="border background  padding margin el-5c7b806f"><h2 class="vce-google-fonts-heading-inner" style="font-family: " open="" sans";="" font-weight:="" 400;"="">'.get_the_title().'</h2></div></div></div><div class="vce-single-image-container vce-single-image--align-center"><div class="vce vce-single-image-wrapper" id="el-9632dafd" data-vce-do-apply="all el-9632dafd"><figure><div class="vce-single-image-inner"><img class="vce-single-image" src="http://ai.crafts-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03.png" data-img-src="http://ai.crafts-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03.png" alt="" title="Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03"></div></figure></div></div><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading vce-google-fonts-heading--align-center vce-google-fonts-heading--color-empty--45--5C00FF--FF7200"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-wrapper"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading--background vce" id="el-8f301bd3" data-vce-do-apply="border background  padding margin el-8f301bd3"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-inner" style="font-family: " open="" sans";="" font-weight:="" 300;"="">'.get_the_content().'</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></a></a>';

    $out .='</div>';
    $out .='</div>';
    endwhile;
    endif;

    foreach($use_case_categories as $use_case_category) {
        //$out .= '<div class="tab-pane" id=" '.$use_case_category->slug.' ">';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'use_cases',
            'posts_per_page' => 11,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $use_case_category->slug,
                    'include_children' => true,
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );

         $films = new WP_Query( $args );

         if ( $films->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $films->have_posts() ) : $films->the_post();
            /*$out .= '<a href='.get_post_meta($post->ID, "location", true).'><div class="vce-row vce-element--has-background vce-row--col-gap-30 use_case_finance vce-row-equal-height vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-6cc8dbe6" data-vce-do-apply="all el-6cc8dbe6"><div class="vce-content-background-container"></div><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-f4a5f49c" data-vce-do-apply="background el-f4a5f49c"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-f4a5f49c"><div class="vce-row-container"><div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-356c02e5" data-vce-do-apply="all el-356c02e5"><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-4c08b71e" data-vce-do-apply="background el-4c08b71e"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-4c08b71e"><div class="vce-row-container"><div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-86253324" data-vce-do-apply="all el-86253324"><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-a1c3851f" data-vce-do-apply="background el-a1c3851f"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-a1c3851f"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading vce-google-fonts-heading--align-center vce-google-fonts-heading--color-b-72-72-72--45--5C00FF--FF7200"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-wrapper"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading--background vce" id="el-5c7b806f" data-vce-do-apply="border background  padding margin el-5c7b806f"><h2 class="vce-google-fonts-heading-inner" style="font-family: " open="" sans";="" font-weight:="" 400;"="">'.get_the_title().'</h2></div></div></div><div class="vce-single-image-container vce-single-image--align-center"><div class="vce vce-single-image-wrapper" id="el-9632dafd" data-vce-do-apply="all el-9632dafd"><figure><div class="vce-single-image-inner"><img class="vce-single-image" src="http://ai.crafts-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03.png" data-img-src="http://ai.crafts-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03.png" alt="" title="Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03"></div></figure></div></div><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading vce-google-fonts-heading--align-center vce-google-fonts-heading--color-empty--45--5C00FF--FF7200"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-wrapper"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading--background vce" id="el-8f301bd3" data-vce-do-apply="border background  padding margin el-8f301bd3"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-inner" style="font-family: " open="" sans";="" font-weight:="" 300;"="">'.get_the_content().'</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></a></a>';
    */
    echo $use_case_category->slug;

    endwhile;
             wp_reset_query();


    endif;
    $out .='</div>';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: what is "bootstrap tabs"?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h

Comment: Where are you defining `$use_case_categories`?

Comment: Sorry I'm going to include all the code better.

Comment: You've just written `global $use_case_categories;`. Where are you *defining* it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter custom post types by custom taxonomy using bootstrap tabs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296633/how-to-filter-custom-post-types-by-custom-taxonomy-using-bootstrap-tabs)

Comment: Inside taxonomy register

Comment: There is way too much irrelevant code in this question. Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/296640/edit) using the [`edit` button above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/296640/edit) and remove any unnecessary code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, next time I will include only relevant code.